# Flutter Firebase Realtime Database listeners not cancelling

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream, listener

I am trying to make a button in flutter which on pressed changes the database reference.

[image]

Like initially the reference points towards the "Comedy" section of the movie. So, if any new movie is added in the comedy section that will be added to the app with the help of onchildAdded.

Now with the press of the button the reference should change to "Horror" section of the movie and if any new horror movie is added to the database, then it should be added to the app. No comedy movie should be added to the app even if it is added to the database.

I tried that but when I press the button it doesn't toggle but adds the reference. Therefore even if a new comedy movie is added to the database it is also added to the app.

I have tried cancelling the SubscriptionStream in a function as well as in the dispose method but this problem doesn't go away.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without seeing a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be hard to say much about this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was finally able to solve it. Initially the cancel subscription was in a function which was firing very quickly. After tweaking it I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem for a while, but there is a workaround.

At the point of cancelling the streamSubscription listener, I simply called the `goOffline()` method on my database instance.

It completely cancelled the listener from underground .

```
final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
database.goOffline()// at the point you want your listener to stop, add this
//To resume or start other database operations 
database.goOnline() //everything works back better
```